# target_include_directories resulting include path

Tags: c++, cmake

Say I have a project that looks like:

```
 Project (dir)
   -- CMakeLists.txt
   -- MyLib (dir)
     |-- CMakeLists.txt
     |-- MyLib.h
     |-- MyLib.cpp

   -- MyOtherLib (dir)
     |-- CMakeLists.txt
     |-- MyLib.h (note that this is exactly the same name as in MyLib above)
     |-- MyLib.cpp
```

If in MyLib/CMakeLists.txt I do this:

```
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
```

Then anything that `target_link_libraries` to `MyLib` will have the "correct" include path to do `#include "MyLib.h"`. However, if another executable `MyExecutable` depends on both libraries using `target_link_libraries(MyExecutable MyLib MyOtherLib)` you'd like to be able to instead specify which one is intended with `#include "MyLib/MyLib.h"` or `#include "MyOtherLib/MyLib.h"`. The only way I see to do that is to instead use:

```
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..>
```

which kind of defeats one of the nice things about `target_include_directories` in that it really strongly enforces avoiding accidental header dependencies, because you literally can't include things that you aren't explicitly claiming to use.

Is there another way to get this `#include "MyLib/MyLib.h"` behavior?

Comment: Having library users which have *different views* of the library's interface (`#include "MyLib.h"` and `#include "Mylib/MyLib.h"`) "defeats" the term *interface* from the point of CMake and from the many other points. You are better redesign the project, so all library's user will view the library through **the same API**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reconsider your directory tree as follows:

```
Project (dir)
   -- CMakeLists.txt
   -- MyLib (dir)
     |-- CMakeLists.txt
     |-- src (dir)
         MyLib.cpp
     |-- include/MyLib (two dirs)
         MyLib.h

   -- MyOtherLib (dir)
     |-- CMakeLists.txt
     |-- src (dir)
         MyLib.cpp
     |-- include/MyOtherLib (two dirs)
         MyLib.h
```

In this way you avoid including the `../`, i.e. `Project`, folder and everything therein, which is not a clean approach and may lead to other problem should you add other files/folders in the future.
Then, you can write in `MyLib/CMakeLists.txt`

```
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>/include)
```

and in `MyOtherLib/CMakeLists.txt`

```
target_include_directories(MyOtherLib PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>/include)
```

As a result, you will be able to write `#include "MyLib/MyLib.h"` and `#include "MyOtherLib/MyLib.h"` in any program linking against the libraries in the *build-tree*.

If you also want to differentiate the include directories between the *build-tree* and the *install-tree* have a look at [target_include_directories documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) and the useful [cmake-generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)).